# Получить значение из строки

Tags: javascript

Есть строка:

```
Исполнитель - Название трека
```

Нужно на JS или JQuery получить из строки `Исполнитель`, но нужно учитывать, что строки могут быть такими:

```
Исполнитель - Название трека
Исполнитель — Название трека
Исполнитель- Название трека
Исполнитель— Название трека
Исполнитель -Название трека
Исполнитель —Название трека

Исполнитель & Исполнитель - Название трека
Исполнитель & Исполнитель — Название трека
Исполнитель & Исполнитель- Название трека
Исполнитель & Исполнитель— Название трека
Исполнитель & Исполнитель -Название трека
Исполнитель & Исполнитель —Название трека
Также учитывать &&
```

А если поиск оказался неудачным, то в `var` выводить всю строку `Исполнитель - Название трека`

Какие методы позволят осуществить подобное?

Comment: `str.split('-')`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ перечислять ключи в `split` можно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` может принимать на вход регулярку, тут подойдет обычное или (`/-|—/`):

```js
let strings = `Исполнитель00 - Название трека
Исполнитель1 — Название трека
Исполнитель2- Название трека
Исполнитель3— Название трека
Исполнитель4 -Название трека
Исполнитель5 —Название трека
Исполнитель6 & Исполнитель12 - Название трека
Исполнитель7 & Исполнитель13 — Название трека
Исполнитель8 & Исполнитель14- Название трека
Исполнитель9 & Исполнитель15— Название трека
Исполнитель0 & Исполнитель16 -Название трека
Исполнитель11 & Исполнитель17 —Название трека`.split('\n')

strings = strings.map(s => s.split(/-|—/).shift().trim().split(' & '))
console.log(strings)
```

Comment: Не подскажите как правильно вывести первое найденное значение? Делаю так `strings[0]` а получаю `[]=Autor`

Comment: strings это массив массивов, соответственно strings[0][0]